# Angular 5 export HTML to pdf after multiple services called

Tags: angular

I have this problem with angular version 5.
I have a review page (parent page) and 5 component page (children page).
when I go to review page It will automatically take snapshot (export HTML to pdf).
But 5 components will call 5 other services to get the latest data and render to HTML.
So when I export HTML to pdf it gets older data not lastest data because some services not done yet.

How can I export HTML to pdf after 5 services called?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :) In order to get better answers and to avoid downvotes, please share your code and what you have tried so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the parent component handle the Service calls and push the results into the Child Components.

parent TS:

```
ngOnInit() {
    forkJoin(
        serviceCall1$, serviceCall2$, //...
    ).subscribe(([result1, result2, result3, result4, result5]) => {
        this.result1 = result1; 
        // ...
        setTimeout(() => {
            // take snapshot
        }, 100) // give angular some time to render, depends when snapshot is actually taken
    })
}
```

parent template:

```
 <child-comp [data]="result1"></child-comp>
 <child-comp [data]="result1"></child-comp>
 <!-- ... -->
```

And in your child components

```
 @Input() data;
```